# Multiple passes of wiping disk with `dd`

Tags: dd, data-destruction

I want to use `dd` to overwrite a disk multiple times to destroy data beyond recovery.

I know I could use `dd if=/dev/zero/ of=/dev/sdx/` to do a pass with zeros, or `dd if=/dev/null/ of=/dev/sdx/` to accomplish similar (not exact same) result, but it will be slower.

I was wondering if there is a way to do something where I could write all zeros, then all ones to a disk using `dd`, or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you tell me how to recover data after a single pass with dd if=/dev/zero?  I've never seen this done.  There used to be a challenge, but I never saw the results:  http://www.hostjury.com/blog/view/195/the-great-zero-challenge-remains-unaccepted

Comment: @umeboshi Certain standards of doing a "complete disk wipe" require doing it 7 times. I used a program before which had 7 passes, and it took about 8 hours to complete. This is why I was looking for another way of accomplishing this multiple times, without having to run that program. I am unsure if it is actually possible to recover it or not, but 7 times will make sure, even if there is less than a 1% chance.

Comment: @umeboshi http://superuser.com/a/512461 this appears to answer how to recover it as well

Comment: If you feel uncertain about dd's ability to wipe data without possibility of recovery, you need physical control over the disk, and physical destruction.  Nothing else will help you ease your mind.  If you can't be sure if one swipe will remove everything, doing it six more times won't help either.  Those "standards" are for a nice little jedi mind trick for the phb's.  What you need is absolute certainty.

Comment: Totally agree with parts of that. It is true that physical control is paramount, and only destruction is truly safe. The next best is improbability. http://askubuntu.com/a/100849/266923 It is possible, probably not probable unless you have expensive stuff according to these guys. It all depends on your data though too :) Although it does appear just a single zero pass really won't help as there are plenty of tools to get your disk back. A pass with urandom looks nice too. The problem is it can miss portions (do `dd if=/dev/sdx | hexdump -C | grep [^00]`) and you can see it misses sometimes

Comment: Here's a link to the peer reviewed paper that was referred to in the original askubuntu question:  http://www.vidarholen.net/~vidar/overwriting_hard_drive_data.pdf

It seems to be more authoritative than an answer from a person saying "I work in the industry and can assure you .... yada yada."  YMMV, but I would take the time to review the paper against the rest of the evidence.  That's why I linked to the challenge in the first place.  It only takes one counterexample to cast doubt on the peer reviewed work of these people.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20559/discussion-between-no-time-and-umeboshi).

Comment: @umeboshi With hard disks made in the 1980s, you could sometimes recover data that had been merely overwritten with zeros, with expensive electronic equipment. Multiple passes of overwrite with random completely removed any chance of that happening. See [Why is writing zeros (or random data) over a hard drive multiple times better than just doing it once?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10464/why-is-writing-zeros-or-random-data-over-a-hard-drive-multiple-times-better-th/10474#10474) On today's disks, overwriting with zeros once is just as good.

Comment: See also [Can Intelligence Agencies Read Overwritten Data? A response to Gutmann.](http://www.nber.org/sys-admin/overwritten-data-guttman.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/sdx` ( note there is no trailing `/` after either device name ) will do nothing, since reading from /dev/null always returns EOF.  Rather than using `dd`, this task is more suited to `shred /dev/sdx`.

Comment: I like this. Can you explain shred a little more (like what it does)? I will look at it a little bit too research wise. It does say in the man, that it has limited effectiveness on ext3+ do journaling. It says you can get around this by messing with fstab. Would rather not have to do this though

Comment: Might want to add  something like this http://security.stackexchange.com/a/62826/66922 as a foot note. As side notes it is perhaps worth mentioning http://security.stackexchange.com/q/5662/66922 (And perhaps things like http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Recovering_Overwritten_Data, http://www.nber.org/sys-admin/overwritten-data-guttman.html) though the latter ones have no effect on a medium suspicious mind. +1

Comment: @NoTime, `shred` overwrites the target with random data multiple times.. i.e. exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user367890 Those are great links. And it appears `dd` would not be a good tool for this really, especially since it is a SSD, rather encrypting drive, or all data then losing the keys, or doing a Secure Erase.

Comment: @psusi After looking at the man page for shred, researching a bit more, and following some of the links in the comments. It appears this would be good probably 99% of the time. However if you have software which can read from the journal, and you have your file system in a certain way (with different mount options) there is a stronger possibility of data recovery.

Comment: @NoTime, since we are talking about shredding the whole disk/partition rather than a file, none of that applies.

Answer (score 1):

The `-kq` option of [`wipe`](http://lambda-diode.com/software/wipe/) is specific for block devices:

```
wipe -kq /dev/hda3
```

Comment: Is this for magnetic only or does it work well with SSD?

Comment: @NoTime That is a different question, and I have no idea whether the same precautions as with disc apply with SSDs. `wipe` has no special instructions for that, but I assume the block wipe would work, although probably overkill.

Comment: It appears that it is not meant for SSDs (HD and FD), but it is an efficient killer of data, so actually it won't matter (except some cases when using RFS). With different switch maybe `-rcf` will be even more effective, because it will do more passes. With the `-q` it does 4 passes using random data (from `/dev/random`). But with the `-rcf` it will recursively do 34 passes rename everything 10 times, then unlink it, and `chmod` things (`-f` forces).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [Darik's Boot And Nuke (DBAN)](http://www.dban.org/) from a live cd/dvd.

Answer (score 1):

The better way is

```
cat /dev/zero >/dev/sdx
```

It doesn't matter what you overwrite with. It did matter with 1980s disks, if you were concerned about attackers with expensive electronic equipment, but it doesn't matter with today's disks. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10464/why-is-writing-zeros-or-random-data-over-a-hard-drive-multiple-times-better-th/10474#10474

Note that this applies to magnetic hard disks only, not to SSD. On SSD, overwriting a sector merely marks it as unused and writes a different sector. If you're concerned about attackers with access to the hardware, it's impossible to be sure that you've wiped the data from the flash memory. Instead, use the SSD's secure erase command, if it has one. But beware that not all SSD models have a secure erase command, and some that claim to have one implement it incorrectly.